# Decreasing the run time for my recursive subset sum algorthim

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, big-o, subset-sum

I have a recursive DFS algorithm that correctly counts the amount of subset sums there are. However, the run time for this method is absurd and extremely exponential. For example, when `arr` contains the set below. The sum we are looking for is 50. The `arr` has all duplicates and numbers greater or equal to 50 removed. The array is then sorted.

21
3
42
10
13
17
33
26
19
7
11
30
24
2
5

`arr` contains the list of words in sorted order

`k` is the intial size of the array

`sum` is the sum we are looking for in the subsets, in this example its 50

```
 public static void recDfs(ArrayList<Integer> arr, int k, int sum) {
    if (sum == 0) {
        counter++;
        return;
    }
    if (sum != 0 && k == 0) {
        return;
    }

    recDfs(arr, k - 1, sum - arr.get(k - 1));
    recDfs(arr, k - 1, sum);
}
```

This will give the correct result extremely quickly, which is posted below

Time elapsed: = 0.004838There are 51 amount of subsets that sum 50
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

However, this algorithm increases exponentially when we have a new set in the array such as.

99
49
1
7
23
83
72
6
202
78
26
79
351
34
107
76
38
50
32
62
71
9
101
77
81
92
89
66
97
57
33
75
68
93
100
28
42
59
29
14
122
24
60
2
37
192
73
84
31
4
87
65
19

When we call the `recDfs` again with the new array that is also sorted and duplicates removed with the sum being 107 the run time is absurd however the correct amount of subsets is printed.

Time elapsed: = 19853.771050There are 1845 amount of subsets that sum 107
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 330 minutes 54 seconds)

I am looking for better ways to implement this algorithm.

Comment: Big hints: Dynamic programming, memoization ;)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: It can also be done with tabulation, but the code will look very different since you will be going bottom-up as opposed to top-down. Regardless, it's a good exercise anyways in DP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some minor optimizations if I understand this correctly:

```
 public static void recDfs(int[] arr, int k, int sum) {
    if (sum < 0) return;

    if (sum == 0) {
        counter++;
        return;
    }
    if (k == 0) {
        return;
    }

    recDfs(arr, k - 1, sum - arr[k - 1]);
    recDfs(arr, k - 1, sum);
}
```

If I'm interpreting this correctly you can bail the branch if the sum is less than 0 which can save a lot of time. (Cannot be done if there are negative numbers) Other minor optimization is to use an int array. This should save a little time over using an ArrayList of Integers. If you want to get fancy you could use multiple threads.